# Shortcode vcvSingleImage not parsed

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I use the free version of WPBakery Builder (Visual composer) and there's a problem with the "Single Image" element which is not parsed on the front-end (but actually is on the admin's "Visual Composer front-end editor"). Every other elements are well parsed...

To be clear, this is what appears on the website's page :

```
[vcvSingleImage class="vce-single-image" data-width="960" data-height="640" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/visualcomposer/elements/singleImage/singleImage/public/single-image.jpg" data-img-src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/visualcomposer/elements/singleImage/singleImage/public/single-image.jpg" alt="" title="" data-default-image="true"]
```

instead of the image itself.

I tried to deactivate all plugins, then only VC, then deinstall and reinstall, but nothing fixes the issue...

The theme i use is homemade.

Any idea ?

Comment: [vc_single_image image="2030"] this should be the correct shortcode for single image element.

Comment: This shortcode doesn't work (maybe because i'm using free version), and this wouldn't be a real solution but a workaround